# How to open and close an action menu using CSS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am creating a floating action button.

My code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a href="#" class="float" id="menu-share">
    <i class="fa fa-share my-float"></i>
</a>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook my-float"></i></a>
    </li>
   <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus my-float"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter my-float"></i></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle Link: [jsfiddle.net/7zkjas08](http://jsfiddle.net/7zkjas08).

Currently in my code when the user click the action button the popup appears and the user need to click or tap in somewhere on the screen to close the popup.

I want functionality like this: [jsfiddle.net/r2hxbL5j](http://jsfiddle.net/r2hxbL5j)

When the user click the button it shows the cross X closing sign. So the user can tap/click the cross sign and popup disappears.

Comment: add your code to the question raher than a link to an external source

Comment: Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code

Comment: @RamRaider sir I added to jsfiddle so other developers can easily check my need. Regards

Comment: This question will likely be closed then my friend..

Comment: Suggest to markup your text to differentiate **link**
btw I dont think this is related to PHP tho

Comment: You have to improve your coding style. Like proper Indentation and I saw that you have not put the link on " jsfiddle.net/7zkjas08". Always link the word if it has some link.

Answer (score 0):

Cool menu, and that you're trying to achieve that with CSS. I wanted to do that myself for a while. What bootstrap is using is something called *pseudo elements* to display the character. You just need to replace that character with something else on hover.

I inspected the `#menu-share` element to find all  this out. Just add the following code, and it will work out.

```
/* when hovering the "a" tag, change the content in the pseudo-element "before" */ 
a#menu-share:hover > i::before{
  content: '✕';
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I added the multiplication character. If you want to go with an X, I suggest that you change the font-family to a sans-serif, like Arial.

---

[edit]
It's IMHO impossible to add close functionality to the button with CSS, so it's needed to add the following functions:

```
/* Old code, but you need to put the next one below this one */
a#menu-share:hover + ul{
  visibility: visible;
  animation: scale-in 0.5s;
}

/* When giving the element focus (=clicking or tabbing to), close */
a#menu-share:focus + ul {
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* Ignore any kind of pointer interaction */
.float > i {
  pointer-events: none;
}


<a onmouseout="this.blur()" href="#" class="float" id="menu-share">
```

`this` means "this element", namely the `a` tag. `blur()` means remove focus from. I also needed to add `.float > i` syntax to the CSS in order for this to work.

Comment: first of all thankyou so much sir you checked my question and answer. I am using this tutorial. http://androidcss.com/demos/css/css-floating-button/floating-button-with-submenu.html. Please check and help me to add a x button like https://getbutton.io/

Comment: sir your code works but i want to also close the div when user click the x. this is the updated code with your suggestion : https://jsfiddle.net/4tozy0vw/

Comment: Awesome sir, it works perfectly on desktop but on mobile devices there is problem. because hover not work in mobile device unless TAP. please help

Comment: You need to use media queries for that. However, older Safari hates `position: fixed` because Apple had an early idea on that they don't want to support code that decreases the scrollable screen. I think newer versions doesn't share that hate.

Comment: hello sir, as you mentioned about media queries can you please share the code.

Comment: I would suggest looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries and go from there. You need to change `a#menu-share:focus + ul` through media queries to instead set `visibility` to visible.